# How to update a large (1 million+ rows) postgres column of jsonb type values

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Trying to update a specific array inside of a jsonb type in a column called params , and having issues with how long it’s taking. For example, there is a table with a row that contains an array owners

```
{
  "hidden": false,
  "org_id": "34692",
  "owners": [
    "tim@facebuk.com"
  ],
  "deleted": false
}
```

And another example

```
{
  "hidden": false,
  "org_id": "34692",
  "owners": [
    "tim@google.com"
  ],
  "deleted": false
}
```

And there’s essentially a million of these rows (all with different email domains as *owners*.
I have this query which I want to execute across all of these rows:

```
UPDATE table 
  set params = CASE 
                 WHEN params->>'owners' NOT LIKE '%google.com%' THEN jsonb_set(params, '{owners}', concat('"', substr(md5(random()::text), 0, 25), '@googlefake.com"')::jsonb) 
                 ELSE params 
               END
```

I’ve tested with a dataset of 100, and it executes perfectly time, but doing this with a 1000x multiple, makes the query forever execute, and I’ve no clue if it will actually successfully complete.  Not entirely sure how to speed up this process or utilize this in a better fashion. I did try indexing e.g. CREATE INDEX ON table((params->>'owners'));  to no avail. Query has run >1 hour, and there are multiple rows similar to this.

Am i indexing incorrectly? Also, I've looked into the gin operator and @> won't help since each owner field differs

Update:

```
UPDATE table AS "updatetarget" 
                 SET params = jsonb_set(params, '{owners}', concat('"', substr(md5(random()::text), 0, 25), '@googlefake.com"')::jsonb)
```

query updated to this and still taking awhile. Is there some way to index the key so i can make the second query faster?

Comment: It will be faster to not update, than to do a dummy update back to the same thing.

Comment: How many rows qualify for the `params->>'owners' NOT LIKE '%google.com%'` condition? If that is only a small percentage, then use a WHERE clause not a CASE expression.

Comment: You have decided for a document based approach by storing data as JSON instead of creating relational tables. You do this, when you don't care about the content's data integrity (data types, mandatory/optional attributes) and you do not care much about the content itself in SQL. The DBMS provides methods to read and manipulate the JSON data, but this tends to be slow. What I am saying is that you voluntarily decided for this design at the cost of speed when working on data inside the JSON. It seems weird that you are complaining about this being slow now. Seems you made a wrong decision.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I'm just working with the current situation that has been presented to me. Unfortunately i was not part of the design process and decision making, but your opinion is valid

Answer (score 1):

Avoid unnecessary updates with a `WHERE` clause that filters out the rows that don't need to be modified.

```
UPDATE table 
  set params = jsonb_set(
                  params,
                  '{owners}',
                  concat(
                     '"',
                     substr(md5(random()::text), 0, 25),
                     '@googlefake.com"'
                  )::jsonb
               ) 
WHERE params->>'owners' NOT LIKE '%google.com%';
```

If a lot of rows are affected, you may want to run `VACUUM (FULL)` once the update is done.

Comment: is there a way to index the text value inside the jsonb  for values that satisfy a certain pattern?

Comment: Actually, this condition is not so easy to index. If you need the update only once, creating an index isn't worth the effort.